# How can I search for the dot character using the search command?

Tags: vim, replace

I'm trying to use the Search command in Vim:

```
:Rs/F/T/X

R = range
F = text to find
T = text to replace with
X = options
```

But, when I want to search for the "." (dot character) I'm getting some problems.

The task: **Replace all occurences of " ." (space dot) for ">" (greater-than)**

So, first I tried this:

```
:%s/ ./>/g
```

But this changed me all the " ." (space ANY-CHARACTER) to the ">" character.

Then I remembered that the dot character is a special one, so I tried this:

```
:%s/ \./>/g
```

But vim threw me an error: **E486 Can't find pattern " \."**

And finally I tried this crazy thing:

`:%s/" ."/>/g` and this `:%s/" \."/>/g`

But I got the same result: **E486 Can't find pattern...**

### So, how can I search for the dot character using the search command?

PS: Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: What a well-asked question :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Both a space and a dot are special characters.  Try this:

```
:%s/\s\./>/g
```

**Update**: \s is used to represent all whitespace characters (space, tab, line break), not just a space.

Comment: Since when is space a special character? `:%s/ \./>/g` works fine for me. You're actually modifying the search by using `\s` to include other kinds of whitespace, not just space.

Comment: Jefromi is right.  I just tried :%s/ \./>/g and it worked.  Not sure if you are on a different version of Vim or what.  I never realized that \s applies to all whitespace (spaces, tabs, line breaks), so keep that in mind if you use the pattern I provided.

Comment: @lk: My guess is that your space character isn't a space character but a tab.

Comment: @Hasturkun: You're probably right (unless it's something weird like a nonbreaking space). I'm tempted to edit the question, because it's not at all about how to search for `.`, but it'd be a pretty big edit.

Comment: @Hasturkun: The character is the simple space character (not tab or somthing like that)
@Ben Hoffstein: I'm using gVim 7.2