# Why regex with any character not matching in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file that I'm editing with vim. I want to delete any character followed by an `_` followed by  a number. This is what I'm editing:

```
some,file_1,file_2,field
groupA_1,/path/to/file1,/path/to/file2,this
groupB_1,/path/to/file1b,/path/to/file2c,that
groupA_2,/path/to/file1,/path/to/file2,this
groupB_2,/path/to/file1b,/path/to/file2b,that
```

I'm using `%s/.\_\d//` which results in

```
some,file,file_2,field
groupA,/path/to/file1,/path/to/file2,this
groupB,/path/to/file1b,/path/to/file2c,that
groupA,/path/to/file1,/path/to/file2,this
groupB,/path/to/file1b,/path/to/file2b,that
```

Note the header keeps `file_2`, and the `A` and `B` are kept. Here is my intended result:

```
some,file,file,field
group,/path/to/file1,/path/to/file2,this
group,/path/to/file1b,/path/to/file2c,that
group,/path/to/file1,/path/to/file2,this
group,/path/to/file1b,/path/to/file2b,that
```

Comment: Shouldn't the expected first line be "some,fil,fil,field"? If you want to delete the character followed by _ and number?

Answer (score 2):

The issues with your regex are:

1. You are not using the `g` flag, and thus only remove the first occurrence on each line
2. `\_\d` matches a digit, `\_` is interpreted as a special construct that makes the next pattern line break aware. So, eventually, your pattern is just equal to `.\d`.

What you want can be achieved with

```
%s/[[:upper:]]\?_\d//g
```

*Details*:

- `[[:upper:]]\?` - an optional uppercase letter
- `_` - an underscore
- `\d` - a digit (use `\d\+` to match one or more digits).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about Vim but the correct regex pattern that matches your cases should be:

```
(?<=.)(_\d*)
```

or

```
(?<=\w)(_\d*)
```

**Interactive demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/W0wdJz/2/)**

Comment: But why is it that `.` does not detect any character? Why would that make a difference?

Comment: Because a dot `.` is a special character in Vim according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821055/how-can-i-search-for-the-dot-character-using-the-search-command ... the problem is when you type `\.` in regex it means a character `.` so I quess u will have to double-escape it somehow ... :)

Answer (score 0):

The `any character` seems to be an uppercase char A-Z.

You can match optional chars A-Z, then an underscore and 1+ digits and replace with an empty string.

Replace all occurrences using the `/g` flag.

```
%s/[A-Z]\?_\d\+//g
```

- `[A-Z]\?` Optinal char A-Z
- `_` Match an underscore
- `\d\+` Match 1+ digits

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Supplement on `\_`

`_` is not special character in regex, we don't need to escape it.
On the other hand, `\_` has special meaning, from [`:help \_`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C_)

```
                        /\_ E63 /\_i /\_I /\_k /\_K /\_f /\_F
                        /\_p /\_P /\_s /\_S /\_d /\_D /\_x /\_X
                        /\_o /\_O /\_w /\_W /\_h /\_H /\_a /\_A
                        /\_l /\_L /\_u /\_U
\_x     Where "x" is any of the characters above: The character class with
        end-of-line added
```

So `\_d` or `\_\d`(second \ has no meaning) are logically same as `[0-9]\|$`, which means digit or end-of-line.

Answer (score 0):

- "Any character, followed by an underscore, followed by a number" is simply `._\d`,
- and you need the `/g` flag if you want all the matches on a line to be substituted,

so here is a correct command:

```
:%s/._\d//g
```

But the `e`s at the end of `file` in this line of the desired result:

```
some,file,file,field
```

are perplexing because they don't follow your requirements, which should yield:

```
some,fil,fil,field
```